# Error in importing tesserocr for using tesseract from python

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, ocr, tesseract

I have installed

- tesseract 4.0.0-143-g7a83
- leptonica-1.74.4.
- tesserocr 2.4.

When I try to import tesserocr, I have the following error:

> ImportError:
>   /home/subrahmanyap/anaconda3/envs/healthy_paws/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tesserocr.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so:
>   undefined symbol: *ZN9tesseract15TessPDFRendererC1EPKcS2*

Comment: [Error while importing "from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI"](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr/issues/9)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to the link. I have already tried the solutions mentioned in that post, and could not resolve the issue.